# nodemon, ts-node, not automatically recompiling

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, ts-node

I am trying to create rest-api using, express+ts-node. I have done all setup based upon online tutorials, and when I run app using `npm run dev` it is working perfectly. But it is not restarting OnSave. This is my package.json script tag:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run nodemon src/index.ts",
    "nodemon": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.ts' -r ts-node/register/transpile-only -r tsconfig-paths/register -r dotenv/config --exec ts-node --files src/index.ts",
    "swagger": "tsoa spec"
  },
```

Looks like nodemon not watching file changes. Please help, how to do restart on save.

Answer (score 1):

try to install the `ts-node-dev` library then use this command in dev:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).